# Storing printed data into variables

Tags: python, iwconfig

I have this code below that prints out the Link Quality & Signal Level of WiFi connection. I'm trying to store the data retrieved into a variables so I could process further but I'm stuck having no idea how to do so.

```
while True:
cmd = subprocess.Popen('iwconfig %s' % args.interface, shell=True,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in cmd.stdout:
    if 'Link Quality' in line:
        print line.lstrip(' '),
    elif 'Not-Associated' in line:
        print 'No signal'
time.sleep(1)
```

Example of the output

```
Link Quality=63/70  Signal level=-47 dBm
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options,

1. Modify the existing code base
2. Write a wrapper over the current executable code

If you go for option 1, I guess it is plain and simple Python code.

If you go for option 2, you will want to parse the `standard output stream` of the existing executable code. Something like this would work:

```
from subprocess import getstatusoutput as gso

# gso('any shell command')
statusCode, stdOutStream = gso('python /path/to/mymodule.py')
if statusCode == 0:
    # parse stdOutStream here
else:
    # do error handling here
```

You can now parse the `stdOutStream` using multiple string operations which shouldn't be difficult if your outputs have a predictable structure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing, save the result into data structure, for examle into list like following:

```
while True:
    result = []
    cmd = subprocess.Popen('iwconfig %s' % args.interface, shell=True,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in cmd.stdout:
        if 'Link Quality' in line:
            result.append(line.lstrip())
        elif 'Not-Associated' in line:
            result.append('No signal')

    # do soemthing with `result`
    #for line in result:
    #    line ...... 

    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the output into a more friendly data structure:

```
import re
results = []
while True:
    cmd = subprocess.Popen('iwconfig %s' % args.interface, shell=True,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in cmd.stdout:
       results.append(dict(re.findall(r'(.*?)=(.*?)\s+', line))
    time.sleep(1)

for count,data in enumerate(results):
    print('Run number: {}'.format(count+1))
    for key,value in data.iteritems():
        print('\t{} = {}'.format(key, value))
```